# What is framework option for mobile web?

Tags: mobile, extjs

So the goal is to make a website which can be accessed by both on Mobile and PC/Desktop.
It is actually form input data but to avoid developing native apps for each Android, IOS and BB we decided to develop web based app.

1. I'm looking at Sencha products, but what consideration to use this compared with GWT or JQueryUI? Some other like KendoUI.
2. How Sencha Touch differ from Sencha GXT? Is it Sencha Touch for javascript/html programmer and Sencha GXT is more suitable for Java programmer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. See this in-depth review and comparison of 5 of the best mobile web application frameworks:

   - [Sencha Touch](http://moduscreate.com/5-best-mobile-web-app-frameworks-sencha-touch/)
   - [jQuery Mobile + Backbone](http://moduscreate.com/5-best-mobile-web-app-frameworks-jquery-mobile-backbone-part4/)
   - [Kendo UI Mobile](http://moduscreate.com/5-best-mobile-web-app-frameworks-kendo-ui-part2/)
   - [AngularJS + Ionic](http://moduscreate.com/5-best-mobile-web-app-frameworks-ionic-angulalrjs/)
   - [React](http://moduscreate.com/5-best-mobile-web-app-frameworks-reactjs/)
2. Sencha Touch is a mobile framework, while GXT is actually a GWT version of Ext JS. While Ext JS supports mobile browsers, it's not primarily suited for mobile applications. Ext JS 5 is said to be much more optimized for mobile devices, but it's going to be a few more months before we see a stable version of Ext 5